# Android JobScheduler: If you schedule the same job with periodic time, does it start the period again?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

What happens if I schedule the same periodic job (same job ID) and the Job has already been scheduled? Does it start its period again from the beginning?

For example, I call this method twice:

```
JobInfo myLongJob = new JobInfo.Builder(
            JOB_ID,
            new ComponentName(context, JobSchedulerLongService.class.getName())
    ).setPeriodic(10000)
     .build();

    jobScheduler.schedule(myLongJob);
```

Does scheduling the job second time cause the periodic timer to start counting again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found it after doing some tests:

> Does scheduling the job the second time cause the periodic timer to start counting again?

**Yes! and...**

It will depend on:

- If the job is being executed: Will cause the first job to stop (calling onStopJob method) and start again.
- If the job is not being executed: Will just start again the countdown.

**Added really useful comment from @Gauthier:**

> jobId - int: Application-provided id for this job. Subsequent calls to cancel,
>   or jobs created with the same jobId, will update the pre-existing job
>   with the same id.
>   [link to this doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#JobInfo.Builder(int, android.content.ComponentName))

Comment: Also worth looking at the JobInfo builder : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#JobInfo.Builder(int%2C android.content.ComponentName)

:jobs created with the same jobId will update the pre-existing job with the same id.

Comment: is there any way to check if my job is already scheduled? I will not re-schedule it.

Comment: @SandeepKumar yes you can use `scheduler.getAllPendingJobs()` check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551385/3212266