# How to check JobService is running or not in android?

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I am using JobService in my project. It's working good. But sometimes service stopped. It is not restart again. So that I am trying to strat the JobService if not running. But I don't know how to check JobService is already running or not. Please let me any idea to how to check JobService is running or not.

My Job service class:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class JobService extends android.app.job.JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        if (NetworkHandler.getInstance().isNetworkAvailable()) {
            TaskHandler.getInstance().getTaskListFromServer(PreferenceManagerForPlannedRoute.getInstance().getLastSyncTime(), PreferenceManagerForPlannedRoute.getInstance().getInProgressMoveTask());
            NotificationUtils.getInstance().CreateNotification();
            Logger.d("Scheduler", "Working!!");
        } else {
            Logger.d("Network", "not available");
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Logger.d("onStopJob", "Stopped");
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Util Class:

```
public class JobSchedulerUtils {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, JobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPeriodic(5000);
        builder.setPersisted(true);           
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
}
```

To start:

```
synchronized public void startAlarmManager() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
            JobSchedulerUtils.scheduleJob(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        }else {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Application.getInstance(), AlarmManagerForPlannedRoute.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Application.getInstance(), 0, myIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Application.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), Constants.TIME_DELAY_FOR_TASK_LIST_SERVICE_CALL_IN_SECONDS * 1000, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

To Stop:

```
 synchronized private void stopAlarmManager(Activity activity) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
            JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            jobScheduler.cancelAll();
        }else {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, AlarmManagerForPlannedRoute.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, myIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android

Comment: @sparkss.. I tried this. It always show job is not running even Job is running successfully..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
public static boolean isJobServiceOn( Context context ) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE ) ;

    boolean hasBeenScheduled = false ;

    for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
        if ( jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID ) {
            hasBeenScheduled = true ;
            break ;
        }
    }

    return hasBeenScheduled ;
}
```

Using of this method we can check jobService is running or not.

Comment: @Alex.F Then how to check job is running or not? Please let me know to improve the my code and answer .

Comment: From API 24 (Nougat) you can use simple `scheduler.getPendingJob(JOB_ID) != null`

Comment: @sosite.. I think I am using the same. Right??

Comment: Nope, you iterate over all pending jobs in place of get only one specific

Comment: Simplified version 
`for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
            if (jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;`

Comment: @hexan. Do you think it will work? If there is 5 jobs running. I want to check the 4th job. In your code while checking first job it will return false. After that loop will not execute. Right? If I am right your simplified version is wrong.

Comment: @NewDeveloper True I will remove my comment. Thanks

Comment: It is worth to mention You should call `jobFinished(mParams, false);` (if You have JobService) at the end of Your job class.

Comment: Is there is any way to check JobDispatcher is running or not?

Comment: Answer is not correct! Question is about Running or Not. Job may be scheduled, but not running.

Comment: The correct answer was provided by @Daniel above. JobService is a service, then, just check if this service is running through ActivityManager class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404522/2212414